# Speed up a slow SQL query on a large database

Tags: php, sql

## This is a picture-type webpage

The code should select the next tag with the least amount of unrated images.

### Table info

#### table_name = images

- filename (varchar255)
- pick (tinyint)
- reject (tinyint)

#### table_name = image_tags

- filename (varchar255)
- tag_name (varchar255)

#### Indexes

The flowing columns has indexes:

- images.filename
- images.pick
- images.reject
- image_tags.filename

### Functionality

The code should go through every row and check how many duplicate tag_name-column there are. Afterwards it should return the tag with the least number of duplicate rows. The code should ignore any rows where `pick = TRUE` or `reject = TRUE`

Meaning the code should only include files if `pick = FALSE` and `reject = FALSE`

### Code

At the moment my code is the folowing.

```
SELECT image_tags.tag_name, COUNT(*) as number_of_rows FROM image_tags JOIN images ON image_tags.filename = images.filename WHERE images.pick = FALSE AND images.reject = FALSE GROUP BY image_tags.tag_name ORDER BY number_of_rows
```

### Question

Because of the size of the database the query takes a lot of time (sometimes as much as 30 seconds). Is there a way to make the query run faster, or is there another query that would have less execution time?

#### Size

- images-table: 700740 rows
- image_tags-table: 823852 rows

Comment: An EXPLAIN on the query will help tell you what indexes (if any) it is using, and to decided what columns you need indexes on

Comment: A join on a varchar255 may be very inefficient. Have you considered adding integer id hash for the filename column in both tables and joining on it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT it.tag_name, COUNT(*) as number_of_rows
FROM image_tags it JOIN
     images i
     ON it.filename = i.filename
WHERE i.pick = FALSE AND i.reject = FALSE
GROUP BY it.tag_name
ORDER BY number_of_rows;
```

The first thing to try is an index on `images(pick, reject, filename)`.  This probably won't help, because boolean columns don't usually whittle down the data enough.  But it is worth a try.

The second thing to try is this query:

```
SELECT it.tag_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM images i
        WHERE it.filename = i.filename AND
              i.pick = FALSE AND
              i.reject = FALSE
       ) as number_of_rows
FROM image_tags it 
GROUP BY it.tag_name
ORDER BY number_of_rows;
```

This moves the aggregation to a subquery, which sometimes performs better in MySQL.  For this, you want an index on `images(filename, pick, reject)`.  Also note that this returns all tags, not just those that have a matching image.  You can filter using `HAVING number_of_rows > 0` if you want the same results as your version.

EDIT:

Oh, I see.  You can try this version:

```
SELECT t.tag_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM image_tags it JOIN
             images i
             ON it.filename = i.filename
        WHERE it.tag_name = t.tag_name AND
              i.pick = FALSE AND
              i.reject = FALSE
       ) as number_of_rows
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tag_name FROM image_tags) t 
ORDER BY number_of_rows;
```

For this, you want indexes on `image_tags(tag_name, filename)` and `images(filename, pick, reject)`.  However, I'm not sure this will have much improved performance.

Comment: Thanks, this reduced the execution time from 20 seconds to less than one second (or at least that is what phpmyadmin says) :)

Comment: At least a 95% improvement.  Cool.

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that the result is never greater than 1, hence most of the functionality gets broken :(

Comment: Still getting nowhere, as this query gives me an error if you insert the word "JOIN" in the query (before "on"), the query executes. But then it takes 30 seconds again.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'images i
             ON it.filename = i.filename
        WHERE it.tag_name = ' at line 4

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper index created for the columns used in `JOIN ON` condition; `WHERE` condition ; `ORDER BY`. In your case you should have index created on

`image_tags.filename` and `images.filename`
`images.pick`; `images.reject`

Also consider running `EXPLAIN` for the query and see what query plan you are getting which will give a better idea.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT image_tags.tag_name, COUNT(*) as number_of_rows FROM image_tags ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the images table has a  int primary key, it would make more sense to have image_id as a foreign key in image_tags table, along with an index on that column.
You will gain in speed and storage space.